# Cypress- Not able to handle Basic Login Authentication Pop Up in Cypress

Tags: cypress, ui-automation, basic-authentication

In cypress we handle the login pop-up authentication for a application by providing username and password in url:

```
cy.visit('https://username:pwd@example.cypress.io')
```

or by providing auth header:

```
cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io/', {
  auth: {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'pwd',
  },
})
```

I tried same logic to handle the application but I can see the login pop-up even after using the passing the credentials in the URL, somehow it is not able to handle this scenario.

Cypress version: 12.8.1

Note: The website https://example.cypress.io/ is just given for reference and the actual website is different, internal website of the company.

Would appreciate any solutions to this

Comment: How do you know the site takes credentials in that format? Does it navigate correctly in the browser?

Comment: When I am trying the same method manually in browser, i.e. by passing credentials in url it is navigating me correctly to home page without any new login pop-up appearing. It is causing trouble when I am using the cy.visit() method

Answer (score 3):

Try upgrading to [Cypress 13.6.1](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#13-6-1) there was a bugfix in that version related to basic auth headers.

> Fixed an issue where pages or downloads opened in a new tab were **missing basic auth headers**. Fixes #28350.

The [issue described](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/28350) is different, but maybe the fix will help your problem also.

> When I need to download a file, it opens another tab in the chromium browser, the credentials are not passed to the new tab, so **I have my api asking me to authenticate again**,

Comment: I tried by upgrading to Cypress 13.6.1 version, but it didn't solved the problem. The login pop up is still appearing ,even after passing credentials to url, also the test case shows passed status in cypress dashboard.